# Stringing on Anycubic Vyper

Tags: stringing, anycubic-vyper

I recently bought a Anycubic Vyper which prints overall not bad but has a real nasty issue with stringing.

I tried out several temperatures, settings for retract distances and retraction speed but nothing seems to really work. All of my filament is new and stringing occurs with different brands so it does not seem to be caused by the filament.

When the nozzle heats up there is molten filament coming out of the nozzle even the extruder is not doing anything at all.

Is there something I can try to fix the stringing apart from taking the hotend apart?

Retraction tower with different retract-values:

[image: 3D print showing stringing]

Retract test which shows the stringing:

[image: 3D print showing stringing#2]

Comment: I'm not sure if it is relevent but do the three photos show any particular stringing at certain temperatures or settings? That is to say, the images seem to shown different amounts of stringing, especially the first image, when compared to the other two. If so, could you [edit] your answer and add anything that might be relevent to the image descriptions and image hover tags. It might help to pin point the issue.

Comment: Is the temperature for the retraction tower the same for all layers? It looks as of the upper part is printed hotter or at a different speed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks for the answers. In this special case the printer had a hardware-defect,so I had to send it back.

I don't know which part in detail was defect but the hotend was switched off in the middle of the print, so either the hotend or something at the mainboard.

Comment: Please accept your answer, else the question will pop up once in a while to the top of the active questions list. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You have a retraction test tower, but consider that a temperature tower is also a useful reference. Your nozzle temperatures may be excessive, especially if you have a substantial oozing from the nozzle when idle.

Consider also that your filament may need drying despite being "fresh out of the box." There are quite a few anecdotes with supporting photos of users printing tests with fresh filament, along with a matching photo of the same test printed after drying the filament in a food dehydrator.