# Stringing problem with Anycubic Vyper

Tags: ultimaker-cura, temperature, retraction, stringing, anycubic-vyper

I replaced my Ender 3 by an Anycubic Vyper, the problem is that all the print have stringing. I tried all the night to change the retraction, change the temperature, but I can get a piece without stringing. By the way, I'm printing PLA, it's dry and I tried from 180 °C to 200 °C.

Does anyone have a Cura profile that works? Or anybody can explain to me what I missed to reach my goal?

Comment: Have you tried dedicated string test prints? There are questions and answers on how to solve this at this Stack. E.g. ["Stringing on Anycubic Vyper"](https://3dprinting.stackexchange.com/questions/20510/stringing-on-anycubic-vyper). Or did you just changed settings and reprinted your object over and over?

Comment: I did a temp tower, and a retract tower. I'm not at home now, but when I'll be at home I'll try to send you picture of it (I don't know if it's possible ...). But to be honest the towers didn't help me a lot.